# New table with row counts

Tags: sql, hive, count, hiveql

I have 5 different tables stored in Hive, and I would like to know how to create a new table, called `total_counts` which has 5 columns each with the total row count from the individual tables. So, something like

[image]

My data is road flights for each year from 2015 to 2019, so I would like a table which just gives me the total number of accidents in each year.

I have tried variations of the following:

```
create table total_counts
as select COUNT(*)
from flights_2014 as "2014_count", flights_2015 as "2015_count;
```

I can get the counts for an individual year, but I can't seem to give the columns a heading, nor can I figure out how to do it for all my tables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE total_counts AS
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM flights_2015) AS 2015_count, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM flights_2016) AS 2016_count;
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate counts in sub-queries and do cross joins if you want to store data in columns

```
CREATE TABLE total_counts AS
SELECT 2015_count.cnt as 2015_count, 2016_count.cnt as 2016_count, ...
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM flights_2015) AS 2015_count
       CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM flights_2016) AS 2016_count
       ...
```

Or the same using UNION ALL + aggregation:

```
CREATE TABLE total_counts AS
SELECT max(case when yr=2015 then cnt else 0 end) 2015_count, 
       max(case when yr=2016 then cnt else 0 end) 2016_count,      
       ...
  FROM (
       SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, 2015 yr FROM flights_2015
       UNION ALL
       SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, 2016 yr FROM flights_2016
       ...
       ) u
```